# error building android core

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I'm following the instructions on http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html , but when i build android_core ,  i came across this kind of problem. I have made the rosjava_core, and the only code i've changed is when installing ant i use "sudo apt-get install ant ant-optional" instead of "sudo apt-get install ant1.8 ant1.8-optional". I have already installed SDK(not from code) and plug-in for eclipse but i have never configured that. can anybody help me on that? Thanks a lot.**

> Building > :android_acm_serial:deployLibs > Resolving dependencies ':android_a:android_acm_serial:deployLibs UP-TO-DATE
> :android_acm_serial:updateProject

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.

> A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

**and that's what i get when run --stacktrace**

:android_acm_serial:deployLibs UP-TO-DATE
:android_acm_serial:updateProject

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.

> A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:67)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build.run(Build.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:116)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$4.call(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:114)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.execute(HandleClientDisconnectBeforeSendingCommand.java:21)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StopConnectionAfterExecution.execute(StopConnectionAfterExecution.java:27)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$1$1.run(Daemon.java:123)
  at org.gradle.messaging.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
  Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting command 'android'.
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:207)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:312)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:91)
  ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: **Cannot run program "android" (in directory "/home/hanbo/my_workspace/android_core/android_acm_serial"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory**
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:69)
  ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  ... 2 more

BUILD FAILED

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33031/error-building-android-core/) by [han](https://answers.ros.org/users/2284/han/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have not properly installed the Android SDK. Make sure you have configured your PATH correctly. Executing "android" in your shell should launch the SDK update utility.

If the android tool is in your path and executes correctly, then it's possible that the gradle daemon is using a copy of your environment before the android tool was installed. Kill the daemon (`ps aux | grep gradle; kill XXX`) and try again.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0